# CSV Files are open with incorrect charset

Tags: csv, character-encoding

The application generates a CSV file with characters such as "ä", "ë", "ï", "ö" or "ü" and when it's open, some characters are incorrectly shown.
For example the expected value to show is:
test-vfde - The hidden edition - Gebühr pro Benutzer Leistungszeit 07/07/16 bis 08/05/16

The value shown is:
test-vfde - The hidden edition - GebÃ‡Å¸â€™?Ã‡?Â¶Â¬hr pro Benutzer Leistungszeit 07/07/16 bis 08/05/16

The only possibility to reproduce this is selecting something different than utf8 charset when I try to open. I believe this is the issue... But how to let the user open the file with a certain charset by default without asking ?. I am under ubuntu 14 with LIbreOffice Calc...